# How to make zsh detect if terminal session is run inside nvim's :term

Tags: neovim, terminal

I were following the *Modern Vim* book by Drew Neil. In tip 20 he writes:

> At a glance, you may not be able to tell whether a shell is running within a terminal buffer or outside of Neovim. In this tip, you’ll find out how you can customize the prompt for your shell so that it appears differently inside of a terminal buffer.

. . .

> When Neovim starts up, it sets the $NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS environment variable. In the start up script for your shell, you can test for the presence of this variable. If $NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS is set, then you can assume that the shell is running inside of a terminal buffer.
> Try adding this snippet to your bashrc file:

```bash
if [ -n "$NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS" ]; then
    export PS1="» "
else
    export PS1="\$ "
fi
```

I found that [`$NVIM_LISTEN_ADDRESS` variable is deprecated](https://neovim.io/doc/user/deprecated.html). I tried to echo it in neovim session, it is empty.

So there is a question, how to detect if zsh or bash session is run inside nvim? (`:term` command)

Comment: You can always set something yourself, e.g., `alias nvim='INSIDE_NVIM=1 nvim'` and then any terminals opened inside `nvim` will have `$INSIDE_NVIM` set for them.

Comment: Could be. I hope it won't interact with `$VISUAL` and other stuff :)

Comment: You can also set the environment variable in nvim's config as well: `let $INSIDE_NVIM = '1'`

Comment: If you are not setting the `$NVIM` environment variable, you can use that one distinguish it. In general, you can just compare the output of `env` inside nvims terminal and outside nvims terminal. Just for reference, Vim exposes the `VIM_TERMINAL` environment variable exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using the following variables:

- `$NVIM/$VIM`
- `$VIMRUNTIME`

those are usually set by the running Vim/Neovim to detect from where to load the initial runtime files. However, for some rare cases (e.g. when Vim/Neovim is not able to figure this out itself), you may set those variable to point Vim/Neovim from where to load its configuration. But usually this should not be necessary.

Therefore Vim also provides the `$VIM_TERMINAL` variable, exactly for this purpose, which also gives you the main Vim version under which the shell is run. See [:h terminal-unix](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-unix)

Comment: Really, `$NVIM` and `$VIMRUNTIME`are set only for current nvim instance and do not influence other zsh sessions. Thanks!